# Failed to build amdgpu-dkms when installing AMDGPU driver on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, dkms, gpu-driver

I'm having trouble to install the drivers for my graphic card AMD radeon RX560 on Ubuntu 20.04. Can someone help me?
I've downloaded the driver on the official AMD site but it fails to install.
Here the output when I try to use the installation script:

```
./amdgpu-install 
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./

... I removed some line because it's too long, no error in the removed part...

Building for 5.4.0-58-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-58-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.
crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/make.log for more informa
tion.
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet amdgpu-dkms (--configure) :
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 10
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de amdgpu :
 amdgpu dépend de amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.14.224-1147286) ; cependant :
 Le paquet amdgpu-dkms n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet amdgpu (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Paramétrage de libatomic1:i386 (10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Aucun rapport « apport » n'a été créé car le message d'erreur indique une erreu
r consécutive à un échec précédent.
                                   Paramétrage de xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amd
gpu (1:19.1.0-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libdrm2:i386 (2.4.101-2) ...
Paramétrage de libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libx11-6:i386 (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Paramétrage de libwayland-egl1:i386 (1.18.0-1) ...
Paramétrage de libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.101-2) ...
Paramétrage de libwayland-client0:i386 (1.18.0-1) ...
Paramétrage de libwayland-server0:i386 (1.18.0-1) ...
Paramétrage de libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.101-2) ...
Paramétrage de libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libxdamage1:i386 (1:1.1.5-2) ...
Paramétrage de libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de gst-omx-amdgpu (1.0.0.1-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.101-2) ...
Paramétrage de libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Paramétrage de libxxf86vm1:i386 (1:1.1.4-1build1) ...
Paramétrage de libllvm10:i386 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Paramétrage de libxfixes3:i386 (1:5.0.3-2) ...
Paramétrage de libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libvdpau1:i386 (1.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Paramétrage de libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de amdgpu-lib (20.40-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.5-1147286) ...
Paramétrage de vdpau-driver-all:i386 (1.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Paramétrage de amdgpu-lib32 (20.40-1147286) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1)
 ...
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
```

Sorry i had to remove some lines because the message was too long.

and here is the make.log file:

```
DKMS make.log for amdgpu-5.6.14.224-1147286 for kernel 5.4.0-58-generic (x86_64)
sam. 26 déc. 2020 13:17:30 CET
make : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic »
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/Makefile:20: "Local GCC version 90303 does not match kernel compiler GCC version 90300"
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/Makefile:21: "This may cause unexpected and hard-to-isolate compiler-related issues"
  AR      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/built-in.a
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/symbols.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mn.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/scheduler/sched_main.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/scheduler/sched_fence.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_memory.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/scheduler/sched_entity.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_ioctl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_memory.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_device_cgroup.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_tt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_bo.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_cache.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_bo_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_device.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence_array.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_kms.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_kthread.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_mm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_pci.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_perf_event.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_reservation.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_suspend.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_workqueue.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_fence.c:30:1: warning: ‘dma_fence_test_signaled_any’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
   30 | dma_fence_test_signaled_any(struct dma_fence **fences, uint32_t count,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_bo_vm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_module.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_execbuf_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_seq_file.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_connector.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_backlight.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_atombios.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_page_alloc.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_pci.c: In function ‘amdkcl_pci_init’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_pci.c:103:84: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘amdkcl_fp_setup’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  103 |  _kcl_pcie_link_speed = (const unsigned char *) amdkcl_fp_setup("pcie_link_speed", _kcl_pcie_link_speed_stub);
      |                                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_pci.c:4:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_common.h:12:63: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const unsigned char *’
   12 | static inline void *amdkcl_fp_setup(const char *symbol, void *fp_stup)
      |                                                         ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/kcl_drm_atomic_helper.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/scheduler/amd-sched.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/dma-buf/dma-resv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_bo_manager.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_agp_backend.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/ttm_page_alloc_dma.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_crtc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_connectors.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/atom.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fence.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ttm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_object.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_gart.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_encoders.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdkcl/amdkcl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_display.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_i2c.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_gem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ring.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/ttm/amdttm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_cs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_benchmark.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_test.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_pm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_dp.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c: In function ‘amdgpufb_create’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:252:14: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  252 |  info->fbops = &amdgpufb_ops;
      |              ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_afmt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_trace_points.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_encoders.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_sa.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_i2c.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_dma_buf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_vm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ib.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_pll.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.c: In function ‘amdgpu_read_platform_bios’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.c:200:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_platform_rom’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  200 |  bios = pci_platform_rom(adev->pdev, &size);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.c:200:7: warning: assignment to ‘uint8_t *’ {aka ‘unsigned char *’} from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  200 |  bios = pci_platform_rom(adev->pdev, &size);
      |       ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ucode.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bo_list.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_ctx.o
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275 : /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.o] Erreur 1
make[2]: *** Attente des tâches non terminées....
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:522 : /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build/amd/amdgpu] Erreur 2
make: *** [Makefile:1757 : /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147286/build] Erreur 2
make : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic »
```

It says that some warnings are being treated as errors and that the local version of GCC doesn't match the version used to build the kernel.
What should I do to install the drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD has released an update solving this issue here:
https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45

I installed it, but there are some bugs and a issue when you boot with the battery charger unplugged (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4 on an HP laptop with an AMD Ryzen 5 3500u). I don't know if this is a kernel problem or driver problem.

Comment: I tried to install the `amdgpu-pro` driver Ver `20.45-1164792` into the kernel `5.4.0-58` and got the same error with `pci_platform_rom`, described in the OP question. So, it's too early to say that "AMD has released an update solving this issue"

Comment: Just info: driver `amdgpu ver. 20.20` works fine with kernel 5.4.0-54.

Comment: I was able to install the `amdgpu-pro` driver Ver `20.45-1188099` into the kernel `5.4.0-62` - so it looks like the problem I've mentioned before has been solved

Answer (score 2):

What AMD released with 20.45 ist also buggy as their former verson. (Sorry for my german version of this.)

```
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket amdgpu-dkms wird gewählt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 231500 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../amdgpu-dkms_5.6.20.906316-1188099_all.deb ...
Entpacken von amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.20.906316-1188099) ...
amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.20.906316-1188099) wird eingerichtet ...
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.20.906316-1188099 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-36-generic 5.8.0-38-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.20.906316-1188099/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 »installiertes amdgpu-dkms-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 10 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 amdgpu-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Ein Paket konnte nicht installiert werden. Wiederherstellung wird versucht:
amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.20.906316-1188099) wird eingerichtet ...
Removing old amdgpu-5.6.20.906316-1188099 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.6.20.906316-1188099
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.20.906316-1188099 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-36-generic 5.8.0-38-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.20.906316-1188099/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 »installiertes amdgpu-dkms-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 10 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 amdgpu-dkms
```

And this happens also for the gen of  amdgpu or amdgpu-pro-dkms.
It seems, that the code in

```
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-36/include/linux/hmm.h
```

is buggy and some vars (-> make.log and crash-report) are not defined.

I'm rather dissapointed.

Comment: It is not "buggy" but it doesn't support this kernel.